# Avoid leading and trailing spaces on Alphanumeric string

Tags: regex, whitespace

I'm trying to validate the string to have only the followings

```
1.  Numbers (0-9) are valid
2.  Letters (A-Z, a-z) are valid
3.  No leading spaces are allowed
4.  No trailing spaces are allowed
5.  A space can be entered in the field text (outside of leading or trailing spaces)
6.  The following special characters are allowed:
    1.  Underscore (_)
    2.  Hyphen (-)
    3.  Comma (,)
    4.  Dot (.)
```

The following is working for me, except spaces

`/^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\_\.\-\,\s]*$/g`

How to avoid **leading spaces** and **trailing spaces** with same Regex pattern?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9_., -]*[A-Za-z0-9_.,-])?$` https://regex101.com/r/B6aKDu/1 or a bit shorter `^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[\w., -]*[\w.,-])?$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there can be consecutive whitespaces characters in between, you could use an optional part where there second character class is repeated 0+ times ending with the same character class excluding `\s`

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9_.,\s-]*[A-Za-z0-9_.,-])?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xx6kcL/1)

Or using `\w` to match word characters:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[\w.,\s-]*[\w.,-])?$
```

Note that `\s` could also possibly match a newline.

Answer (score 1):

The **leading spaces** can be forbidden with `(?!\s)` lookahead.

The **trailing spaces** can be forbidden with `(?!.*\s$)` lookahead.

Combine them into your pattern after `^`:

```
/^(?!\s)(?!.*\s$)[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\_\.\-\,\s]*$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/NiOd41/1)